# Deducing std::function with more than two args

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

I wonder why [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is only aware of two-argument functions. I've written some code which is working well, but there are a number of limitations. Any feedback welcome. In particular, I suspect I'm reinventing the wheel.

My code is on [ideone](http://ideone.com/vCegX) and I will refer to it.

For example, I can describe the type of `main` with:

```
function_type_deducer(main).describe_me();
// Output: I return i and I take 2 arguments.  They are of type:  i PPc
```

(where 'i' means 'int' and 'PPc' means pointer-to-pointer-to-char)

Standard `std::function` doesn't work with functions with more than two args (see the last two lines of my code), but this code does (the sample code demonstrates three-arg functions). Maybe my design should be used in the standard library instead! I define `typedef tuple<Args...> args_as_tuple;` to store all args, not just the first two argument types.

The main trick is the deduction in this function:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
auto function_type_deducer(T(Args...)) -> Function__<T, Args...> {
        return Function__<T, Args...> {};
}
```

Limitations:

- It doesn't work with lambdas. This won't compile `function_type_deducer([](){}).describe_me();`
- It doesn't notice that there is a small difference between `x` and `y`, as `y` takes a `string&`, where `x` takes a `string`. (std::function doesn't notice this either)

Any ideas on how to fix either of these? Have I reinvented the wheel?

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482680/146041) is relevant to my lambda question. And maybe [Boost.Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/index.html) has answers to all this, judging by that answer. Maybe this is a dupe after all!

Comment: `std::function<>` only contains `argument_type`, `first_argument_type`, and `second_argument_type` typedefs for backwards compatibility with C++98/03 code oriented around pre-TR1 function adapters. Essentially they are legacy and in C++11 you should do your best to pretend they don't exist.

Comment: @ildjarn: What's the C++11 method for getting the type of parameter *n*?  Sounds like it would be a valid answer.

Comment: @Drew : Unpacking `Args...` into a `std::tuple<>` typedef then accessing tuple elements by index would be my guess, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about variadic templates to post a real answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This won't compile `function_type_deducer([](){}).describe_me();`

It would work if `function_type_deducer` wasn't a template. :) Non-capturing lambdas (empty `[]`) are implicitly convertible to function pointers. Sadly, implicit conversions aren't taken into consideration for some template argument deduction. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513050/500104) for more information (note that my answer isn't completely correct as the comments indicate).

---

> It doesn't notice that there is a small difference between x and y, as y takes a string&, where x takes a string.

That's not a problem with the function, that's a problem with `typeid`, as this simple testcode shows:

```
template<class T>
void x(void(T)){
    T v;
    (void)v;
}

void f1(int){}
void f2(int&){}

int main(){
    x(f1);
    x(f2);
}
```

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/YtDli). Output:

> error: ‘v’ declared as reference but not initialized

A simple fix might be using tag dispatching:

```
#include <type_traits> // is_reference
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T>
void print_name(std::true_type){
  std::cout << "reference to " << typeid(T).name();
}

template<class T>
void print_name(std::false_type){
  std::cout << typeid(T).name();
}

template<class T>
void print_name(){
  print_name(typename std::is_reference<T>::type());
}
```

And call `print_name<NextArg>()` instead of `typeid(NextArg).name()`.

---

> Have I reinvented the wheel?

Yes, kind of and no, you didn't. [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html) provides typedefs for all arguments (`argN_type` style), aswell as the static constant `arity` for the number thereof. However, you can't easily access those typedefs generically. You would need a roundabout way to not accidentially access non-existant ones. The `tuple` idea works best, however it can be written in a nicer way. Here's a modified version of something I once wrote:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace detail{

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_name(std::ostream& os);

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_pointer(std::ostream& os, std::true_type){
  typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>:: type np_type;
  os << "pointer to ";
  return print_name<np_type>(os);
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_pointer(std::ostream& os, std::false_type){
  return os << typeid(T).name();
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_name(std::ostream& os, std::true_type){
  return os << "reference to " << typeid(T).name();
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_name(std::ostream& os, std::false_type){
  return print_pointer<T>(os, typename std::is_pointer<T>::type());
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& print_name(std::ostream& os){
  return print_name<T>(os, typename std::is_reference<T>::type());
}

// to workaround partial function specialization
template<unsigned> struct int2type{};

template<class Tuple, unsigned I>
std::ostream& print_types(std::ostream& os, int2type<I>){
  typedef typename std::tuple_element<I,Tuple>::type type;

  print_types<Tuple>(os, int2type<I-1>()); // left-folding
  os << ", ";
  return print_name<type>(os);
}

template<class Tuple>
std::ostream& print_types(std::ostream& os, int2type<0>){
  typedef typename std::tuple_element<0,Tuple>::type type;
  return print_name<type>(os);
}

} // detail::

template<class R, class... Args>
struct function_info{
  typedef R result_type;
  typedef std::tuple<Args...> argument_tuple;
  static unsigned const arity = sizeof...(Args);

  void describe_me(std::ostream& os = std::cout) const{
    using namespace detail;
    os << "I return '"; print_name<result_type>(os);
    os << "' and I take '" << arity << "' arguments. They are: \n\t'";
    print_types<argument_tuple>(os, int2type<arity-1>()) << "'\n";
  }
};
```

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/iySpC). Output:

```
main:   I return 'i' and I take '2' arguments. They are: 
        'i, pointer to pointer to c'
x:      I return 'Ss' and I take '3' arguments. They are: 
        'i, Ss, c'
y:      I return 'Ss' and I take '3' arguments. They are: 
       'i, reference to Ss, c'
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. I just found another ridiculously simple template via [C++Next](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/11/expressive-c-trouble-with-tuples/). Just look at [this brief snippet](http://ideone.com/7mSkK) on ideone. It's as if the specialization has more template parameters than the original template!

Comment: @Aaron: Well, grats, that's how `std::` and `boost::function` are implemented. ;) (And even how it's specified in the standard.)

Answer (score 1):

The link to the answer with the lambda function provides the critical hint: you need to obtain a pointer to a member function for the function call operator. That is, if `T` is a function object, you need to look at `&T::operator()`. With generalized SFINAE you can determine if this function call operator exists. Putting this stuff together in a possibly somewhat roundabout way, yields this (which compiles with a recent version of gcc and clang, except for the lambda function which isn't supported, yet, by clang):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct S {
    void f(int, std::string&, void (*)(int)) {}
    void g(int, std::string&, void (*)(int)) const {}
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T> struct describer;
template <> struct describer<S>;
template <> struct describer<int>;
template <> struct describer<void>;
template <> struct describer<std::string>;
template <typename T> struct describer<T&>;
template <typename T> struct describer<T*>;
template <typename T> struct describer<T const>;
template <typename T> struct describer<T volatile>;
template <typename T> struct describer<T const volatile>;
template <typename T, int Size> struct describer<T(&)[Size]>;

template <typename T> struct describer {
    static std::string type() { return "???"; }
};
template <> struct describer<S> {
    static std::string type() { return "S"; }
};
template <> struct describer<void> {
    static std::string type() { return "void"; }
};
template <> struct describer<int> {
    static std::string type() { return "int"; }
};
template <> struct describer<std::string> {
    static std::string type() { return "std::string"; }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T&> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string("&"); }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T&&> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string("&&"); }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T*> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string("&"); }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T const> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string(" const"); }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T volatile> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string(" volatile"); }
};
template <typename T> struct describer<T const volatile> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + std::string(" const volatile"); }
};
template <typename T, int Size> struct describer<T(&)[Size]>
{
    static std::string type() {
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "(array of " << Size << " " << describer<T>::type() << " objects)&";
        return out.str();
    }
};

template <typename... T> struct description_list;
template <> struct description_list<> { static std::string type() { return std::string(); } }; 
template <typename T> struct description_list<T> { static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type(); } };
template <typename T, typename... S> struct description_list<T, S...> {
    static std::string type() { return describer<T>::type() + ", " + description_list<S...>::type(); }
};

template <typename R, typename... A>
struct describer<R(*)(A...)>
{
    static std::string type() {
        return "pointer function returning " + describer<R>::type() + " and taking arguments"
            + "(" + description_list<A...>::type() + ")";
    }
};

template <typename R, typename S, typename... A>
struct describer<R(S::*)(A...)>
{
    static std::string type() {
        return "pointer to member function of " + describer<S>::type() + " returning " + describer<R>::type() + " "
            "and taking arguments" + "(" + description_list<A...>::type() + ")";
    }
};

template <typename R, typename S, typename... A>
struct describer<R(S::*)(A...) const>
{
    static std::string type() {
        return "pointer to const member function of " + describer<S>::type() + " returning " + describer<R>::type() + " "
            "and taking arguments" + "(" + description_list<A...>::type() + ")";
    }
};

template <typename T> char (&call_op(decltype(&T::operator())*))[1];
template <typename T> char (&call_op(...))[2];

template <typename T> struct has_function_call_operator { enum { value = sizeof(call_op<T>(0)) == 1 }; };

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_function_call_operator<T>::value>::type describe(std::string const& what, T)
{
    std::cout << "describe(" << what << ")=" << describer<T>::type() << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_function_call_operator<T>::value>::type describe(std::string const& what, T)
{
    std::cout << "describe(" << what << ")=function object: " << describer<decltype(&T::operator())>::type() << "\n";
}


int f(std::string, std::string const&, std::string&&) { return 0; }
int g(std::string&, std::string const&) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    describe("int", 1);
    describe("f", &f);
    describe("g", &g);
    describe("S::f", &S::f);
    describe("S::g", &S::g);
    describe("mini-lambda", []{}); // doesn't work with clang, yet.
    describe("std::function<int(int(&)[1], int(&)[2], int(&)[4], int(&)[4])>",
             std::function<int(int(&)[1], int(&)[2], int(&)[4], int(&)[4])>());
}
```

Comment: @Xeo: clang is coming along quite well, I think. I don't know what their agenda is. I would definitely like to use lambda-functions but this seems to be something better not, yet, to be relied on.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, good answer also, but I think I'll accept Xeo's because his code was a little shorter. [ It's like [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) "Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code." :-) ]